At what point in Salah should I recite the dua اللهم إني أسألك الثبات في الأمر
I found a hadith in Sunan an-Nasa'i 1304

It was narrated from Shadad bin Aws that: The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ)
used to say in his prayer: "Allahumma inni as'aluka at-thabbuta fi
al-amr wal-'azimata 'alar-rushdi wa as'aluka shukr ni'matik wa husna
'ibadatik wa as'aluka qalban saliman wa lisanan sadiqan wa as'aluka
min khairi ma at'lamu wa author bika min sharri ma at'lamu
wastaghfiruka lima ta'lam (O Allah, I ask You for steadfastness in all
my affairs and determination in following the right path, I ask You to
make me thankful for Your blessings and to make me worship You
properly. I ask You for a sound heart and a truthful tongue. I ask You
for the best of what You know and I seek refuge in You from the worst
of what You know and I seek Your forgiveness for what You know.)"

My question is at what rukon (Ruku/Sajdah/....) shall i say this dua.

You can say it in the parts where dua is prescribed, such as after the last tashahhud and salawat - or during sujood etc. A version in  Musnad Ahmad states that it was at the end of Salah.

Jazak Allah Brother.
